# kendo scheduler hide timeline rows if there are no events

Tags: kendo-scheduler

How to hide kendo scheduler timeline rows if there are no events on the week. Did anyone face similar issue or have idea to solve this?
How to decrease height of k-slot?. I tried the following css but no luck

```
.k-scheduler-dayview .k-scheduler-table td,
.k-scheduler-weekview tr:nth-child(2) .k-scheduler-table td,
.k-scheduler-monthview .k-scheduler-table td {
   height: 1em;
     padding: .334em .5em;
     font-size: 100%;
}
```

Can anyone resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

The desired behavior (if I understand you correctly that you need to filter the groups when no events are available in given group) would require custom solution. For example you can use the [`dataBound`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/scheduler#events-dataBound) event to check if given group have no events inside it. You can check how many events are rendered in each group by checking the `groups` property of the current view (which gen be get from [`view`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/scheduler#methods-view) method). Finally you can hide the groups that you don't need by filtering the target resource dataSource (e.g.: [`scheduler.resources\[0\].dataSource.filter`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#methods-filter)).